# Mobile Safari halts page load with 404 on jquery.min.map file

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari, source-maps

Our web application halts page initialization on a single error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://foo.com/pkg/jquery/js/jquery.min.map
```

This is really weird behaviour as it has appeared quite recently.

I'm not sure on how to check which mobile Safari version I have but I think my iPad has a late version of iOS 8. This problem doesn't appear with an older iPhone 4, only with newer iOS versions 8 and/or 9. While desktop Safari is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that while I started using local jquery asset instead of CDN, I had forgotten to add sourcemap file. Still odd that that newer iOS's Safari stopped page load on that missing asset.